# How to add FirebaseUI-iOS to an ios project without using CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebaseui

I am creating an iOS app in which I would like to use [FirebaseUI-iOS](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS).

I am currently using Carthage to manage the dependencies.

FirebaseUI-ios does not currently support carthage ([issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/297))

The following information is provided in the README of the FirebaseUI-iOS project.

> Otherwise, you can download the latest version of the [FirebaseUI frameworks from the releases
>   page](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/releases) or include the FirebaseUI
>   Xcode project from this repo in your project. You also need to [add the Firebase
>   framework](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) to your project.

However, I do not know exactly how to add the FirebaseUI project after downloading the release file.

Can someone point out how I can add the FirebaseUI-iOS framework to an iOS project without using CocoaPods?

Comment: Perhaps you can download the API from here and integrate it manually.  https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS

Comment: @DaveStrand Yes, the question that I have asked is actually regarding how to do the manual integration.

Comment: Gotcha..  Maybe this tutorial will help.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup .   (Sorry, maybe this ends up using Cocoapods as well.) . I think I ran across something similar in the past and ended up using Homebrew to enable Cocoapods.  (Which our IT director was not too thrilled about)

Comment: @DaveStrand In the end, I had to use CocoaPods to install Firebase. Thanks for the help

Comment: IT would be really great to know how to do this!

Comment: I would be interested in a solution to this as well!